# UserControl behind code getting very large

Tags: wpf, user-controls

I have a media control user control (inside my library that is basically a set of x buttons that a developer can customize. I placed over 4 dependency properties per button on the usercontrol to customise the buttons image, tooltip, command, visibility ect. the problem is that the behind code is now becomming very large. over 1000 lines of code already. Is there a best practice im missing here.

upon researching about usercontrols in librarys, i understood not to use the mvvm approch, have i got this wrong

here is an image of the control (very unfinished)[image: Image of usercontrol media control]

This is the code a developer would use to create the usercontrol in their view:

```
<myLibrary:MediaControl     VerticalAlignment="Bottom"
                            Title="{Binding Path=FileName}"
                            PlayTime="{Binding Path=PlayTime}"
                            StopClickCommand="{Binding Path=StopCommand}"
                            StopToolTipMessage="This is the stop button!"                                                           
                            RewindClickCommand="{Binding Path=RewindCommand}"
                            PlayClickCommand="{Binding Path=PlayCommand}"
                            PauseClickCommand="{Binding Path=PauseCommand}"/>
```

Comment: yeah thats the thing. i love mvvm but i think i read somewhere not to do it in this case, thats the only reason i didnt. if i find it again i will link it thanks. i believe it was something to do with lookless controls

Comment: Is this a reusable user control? @Sam

Comment: Well id like to make it in a way that anyone could reuse it easily from the library im making

Comment: Without seeing your code I can't comment much. But still the way you're following seems to be good.  You can't have a view model for a reusable control.  Just bind all button clicks to commanda using dependency properties ie while reusing the control,  you can specify the command in the corresponding view model.  Hope you got the point. Still I don't understand how you got that many lines of code.

Comment: i think its because i have dependency properties for over 10 buttons, i also have around another 3 or 4 for dependency properties per button for things like visibility, image, tool tip message ect. which adds up to over 40 dependency properties at least. sounds like its being done right just something slightly annoying

Comment: Then create a button reusable control,  and use it.  Thats the best thing. But what you're saying doesn't sound that good.  Why do you want to control each button's image tool tip etc from main page.  It would make your code definitely long and complicated. Anyways what you're doing is not wrong.  But yoy need to try to optimize it. Else you may face performance bottlenecks while uaing this in a larger application.

Comment: well if you dont overwrite the images ect then the control will use defaults, just giving the user of the control plenty of options. doesnt mean they all have to be defined by user

Comment: Then what you're doing is perfectly correct. There is not much modifications required.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

[`DataGrid`](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#PresentationFramework/src/Framework/System/Windows/Controls/DataGrid.cs,0a7919e43781659b) class contains 8678 lines of code.

[`Grid`](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#PresentationFramework/src/Framework/System/Windows/Controls/Grid.cs) class contains 3393 lines of code.

[`MediaElement`](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#PresentationFramework/src/Framework/System/Windows/Controls/MediaElement.cs,5248739ecf64870c) class contains 985 lines of code.

You should know how to segregate the things, keeping related things together.

*For eg*, if you see the code of `DataGrid` you will see how it also uses many smaller helper classes. So, you should take a look at how these controls and other ones work, this is the best way.

I strongly recommend [ILSPY tool](http://ilspy.net/) to peek into .net classes' source code.

Also you can view the source code online at [referencesource.microsoft.com](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#PresentationFramework/src/Framework/System/Windows/Controls/Grid.cs,f9ce1d6be154348a).

Comment: Thank you thats a good idea. i'll take a look into the controls. Im not too fond of this many lines in 1 class is all. but i suposse mvvm id end up with a massive vm full of the same paramaters as the c# back end has anyway

Comment: @Sam You are creating a new Control, so better look at some standard controls like I mentioned.

Comment: seems these do as you said. giant classes full of code